# How to use theme object with makeStyles without ThemeProvider in Material UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a custom theme object set up like this:

```
import palette from './palette';
import typography from './typography';


const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette,
  typography,
}));

export default theme;
```

In MUI, `useStyles()` can directly access `theme` when the component is wrapped with `<ThemeProvider>`.

```
import theme from "../src/themes/index";

<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
   <Button/>
</ThemeProvider>
```

But instead, I'd like to import `theme` then directly pass it to `makeStyles()` but I haven't had any lucks so far. How do I solve this?

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import theme from "../src/themes/index";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
(...)
});

const Button = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    (...)
}
```

Comment: When you do `useStyles(theme)`, you can access the theme you passed in as follows: `color: props => props.primary.main`. But I'd suggest using nested `ThemeProvider` as @CevaComic mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the best option, but it works:

```
const useStyles = theme => {
  return makeStyles(() => ({
  (...)
  })
}

// and use it this way:

const classes = useStyles(theme)()
```

You can use nested `ThemeProvider` in Material-UI, so I think that will be the best choice in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this method and it works for the most part (typography is not properly loading for some reason on my end). What other methods would you recommend? It does not have to use makeStyles() as long as I can directly import theme object to the component.

Comment: You can use ```withStyles``` and not create a whole ```theme``` to style only one type of component. [Documentation here](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#higher-order-component-api) , also you have alot of examples on how to use ```withStyles``` in other examples on material-ui website. (There is a good one [here](https://material-ui.com/components/steppers/#customized-stepper).)

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but `makeStyles` has the ability to pass in an `options` object as a second argument. One of the keys on the options object is `defaultTheme`.

`options.defaultTheme (Object [optional]): The default theme to use if a theme isn't supplied through a Theme Provider.`

https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#makestyles-styles-options-hook

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
 // styles
}), { defaultTheme: theme });
```